# How does wait() and notify() work in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, notify

I am new to OS/multithreading and I'm wondering how `wait()` and `notify()` work together. I just saw this: [Producer Consumer Solution in Java](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/producer-consumer-solution-using-threads-java/)

And I'm kind of confused. Let's say I called `wait()` in `PC.consume()` method. When I reach the line that says `notify()` in `PC.produce()`, how does this wait in `PC.consume()` know that THAT is the one being notified? There could be other places that could be notified so how does it exactly know which to notify?

Thanks!

Comment: What does the javadoc say?

Comment: It doesn't: see [Object.notify](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notify--).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wait and notify are called on the same object, the one being used as a lock (in the example that’s the object referenced by the local variable pc).  The term used in the javadoc (here is the start of the api doc for the notify method) is “monitor”:

> Wakes up a single thread that is waiting on this object's monitor. If any threads are waiting on this object, one of them is chosen to be awakened. The choice is arbitrary and occurs at the discretion of the implementation. A thread waits on an object's monitor by calling one of the wait methods.

The OS has a thread scheduler that is making the arbitrary decision described in the javadoc, it decides things like when threads get context-switched or who gets notified.

So when a thread in consume waits, it goes dormant. Then eventually some other thread (in the example there are only two threads that acquire the lock on pc) calls notify on the same object the first thread called wait on, the scheduler picks the thread to be notified (has to be the first thread here because nothing else is waiting), and the notified thread wakes up and checks if there is anything to consume so it can know whether to proceed.

Comment: Thanks, what if there are 2 threads waiting,can this case undefined behavior?

Comment: @Bhatnag: no. The scheduler decides which waiting thread gets notified. It can decide based on any reason or even randomly, hence the “the choice is arbitrary” line in the javadoc. (In the case of this example code, adding more threads would lead to missed notifications, because a thread could get notified for a condition it isn’t interested in. But that isn’t undefined behavior, it’s just a bug. )

Comment: Hi. I meant to ask, if I have two threads waiting and 1 notifies, I won't know which one is being notified. Is this true?

Comment: @Bhatnag: true. there's no telling which thread will be notified.

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful :)